# WebApi 2 not using Domain Model Dbcontext connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I using n-tier architecture, so now I have 2 project Domain and Service(WebApi2)

[image]

- I'm using MySql for my project
- I have implemented my own Identity User and MySqlConfiguration for EF
- I have run update-database and it updating it correctly

[image]

- But when I'm using it in my Service, my connection    string is 
  `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DefaultConnection;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True`

My App.config from Domain

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=admin123;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=GD" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
          type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity"/>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"></remove>
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
          invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
          description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
          type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

In Startup.Auth.cs I added my custom implementation of User and

`UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<User>(new UserRepository());`

UserRepository is using my Entity

```
 public UserRepository()
    {
        _entities = new Entities();
    }
```

Entity.cs:

```
public class Entities : DbContext
{
    static Entities() 
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
    }

    public Entities() : base("DefaultConnection") { }

    public DbSet<User> IdentityUsers { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Role> IdentityRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IdentityUserClaim> IdentityUserClaims { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IdentityUserLogin> IdentityUserLogins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IdentityUserRole> IdentityUserRoles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(u => u.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(u => u.RoleId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(u => u.UserId);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Q: How to make project Service to use Domain connection string ?**

Comment: Why would it use the config file from your Domain? The config file from your Service is **the** config file that your app-domain will use.

Comment: Why do you need this? If you don't use the connection string from the Service you lose flexibility because you cannot change the connection string without deploying new version.

Comment: Actually the config file from top level dll is used. If you have UI/Web.dll -> Service.dll -> Domain.dll, the config file from UI/Web.dll is used.

Comment: So i need to have 3 connection string in separate configs?

Comment: @AndrianDurlestean One config in assembly you actually run is enough. Using my example: place your config under UI project.

Comment: For example if your domain project is referenced in service project, and service project is referenced in your web project then your web project should contain the connection string, and not any other project. All upper level projects should use that connection string from lower level project.

Comment: Please add it as separate answer for approve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration Manager uses configuration file from entry project by default. Basically you shouldn't place configuration in dependent assemblies.

So if you have a reference chain like **UI <- Services <- Domain**, you should place your config file under UI project.

Answer (score 2):

When your project runs, the only used configuration file is the one in the start up project (in your case, the Web API project). So you need the connection string in its web.config file.

*NOTE: if you had a test project to test the Web API, then that would be the start up project, and you'd need to add the connection string to that porject's config file. If not the test runner wouldn't find it, and the test would fail*